# Converting XML to CSV with xmlstarlet with no success

Tags: xml, csv, xmlstarlet

I have a XML document that is formatted as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appname version="2.3">
  <system name="web host">
    <username><![CDATA[username1]]></username>
    <password><![CDATA[password1]]></password>
    <note><![CDATA[]]></note>
    <url><![CDATA[]]></url>
  </system>
  <system name="vendor name">
    <username><![CDATA[username@email.com]]></username>
    <password><![CDATA[password2]]></password>
    <note><![CDATA[]]></note>
    <url><![CDATA[]]></url>
  </system>
  <system name="vendor name 3">
    <username><![CDATA[username@email.com]]></username>
    <password><![CDATA[password3]]></password>
    <note><![CDATA[]]></note>
    <url><![CDATA[]]></url>
  </system>
<appname>
```

I am trying to use:

```
xmlstarlet \
  sel -T -t -m /root/system \
  -v "concat(@name,',',username,',',password,',',note,',',url)" \
  -n filename.xml
```

and I get:

> ```
> failed to load external entity "concat(@name,',',username,',',password,',',note,',',url)-n"
> ```

I just want a tab delimited document from the current one so I can import it into another password manager. I have hundreds of entries I would really like to not have to retype.

Can anyone help?

Comment: That error sounds like a quoting issue. What are you running xmlstarlet on? If I change `/root` to `/appname` (and fix the appname end tag) your command line works for me using bash in cygwin.

Comment: I'm using it with Brew on Mac OS 13.

Answer (score 2):

Using Xidel:

```
xidel -s vendor.xml -e "/appname/system/join((./@name, ./username/text(), ./password/text()), x:cps(9))"
```

Produces:

```
web host        username1       password1
vendor name     username@email.com      password2
vendor name 3   username@email.com      password3
```

Thanks to @Reino for trick to print TAB chars and arg placement.  Tested quotes on cmd.exe and Cygwin bash.

Comment: XPath: `-e '//system/join((@name,username,password),x:cps(9))'`. XQuery: `--xquery '//system/join((@name,username,password),"&#9;")'`. `--printed-node-format=text` isn't necessary, because it's the default anyway. Also please put the input, _'vendor.xml'_, in front of the extraction-query. And finally please mind the quotes. OP is using Mac OS which requires Unix quoting.

Answer (score 1):

The long and convoluted answer is you need to use something like

```
xml sel -T \
  -t -m '//system' \
     -v '@name' \
     -o ' ' \
     -v './username' \
     -o ' ' \
     -v './password' \
     -o ' ' \
     -v './note' \
     -o ' ' \
     -v './url' \
-n file.xml
```

which, based on your xml, outputs:

```
web host  username1 password1  
vendor name  username@email.com password2  
vendor name 3  username@email.com password3
```

The shorter (and better, imho) answer is using something more advanced like xidel.

Comment: The `./` (i.e. in front of `-v './username'`) is not needed, you also can do `-v 'username'`, where even the quotes around username or not needed.

Comment: @JackFleeting Having trouble doing this (similar) with Xidel.  Can you give an example?